# React JS SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm, redux

I'm trying to run an NPM script named **foo** defined in `package.json` with `ts-node` but the following error throws.

> (node:94440) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> /Users/vinaysharma/Sites/projects/the-seasoned-dev/src/scripts/foo.ts:1
> import { x } from './bar';
> ^^^^ SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Below is the file that I'm trying to run with `npx ts-node src/scripts/foo.ts`.

**foo.ts**

```
import { x } from './bar';

console.log(x);
```

**bar.ts**

```
export const x = 1;
```

**folder structure**

```
|_node_modules
|_public
|_src
| |_scripts
| | |_foo.ts
| | |_bar.ts
| |_App.tsx
| |_App.css
| |_index.tsx
| |_index.css
|_package.json
|_package-lock.json
|_tsconfig.json
```

#### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.6.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.16",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "foo": "npx ts-node src/scripts/foo.ts"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1"
  }
}
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Comment: Try adding `type: 'module'` in package.json or rename imports statement to require